# "Hotel & Companies **that** we work with" VS "Hotel & Companies we work with"

Tags: that

'Hotels & Companies **that** we work with, in the UAE'

I have been told that I should not use **that** as it hampers the readability. Any Suggestions! Is it really wrong to use **that** in the above example?

The original sentence is - "Would you forward me the list of Hotels & Companies **that** we work with, in UAE?'

Comment: There's no constraint other than style preference. I think my choice would be informed by the actual complete sentence. Do you have one?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I have provided the original sentence I wrote. Do suggest something about the use of **that** when writing a heading ('Hotels & Companies that we work with, in the UAE'). I know that **that** can be skipped but would it be considered wrong if I choose to retain it.

Comment: I prefer the keeping of 'that' here; it sounds more formal. Although neither variant can be said to be incorrect. But I'd certainly drop the comma.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. I added the comma because Grammarly software was suggesting me to replace **with in** with **within**

Comment: The "that" in the abbreviated version is implied. A native speaker would have no problems with this and could interchange between both ways, but a non-native speaker might have a bit of trouble making sense of the abbreviated version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question about style and communication.

Know your audience.

If your readers are native English speakers then you can often drop such occurrences of *that*.

Otherwise, keeping them can help at least some readers for whom English is not their first language. In particular, it can help those whose native language(s) would use something equivalent to *that*.

In addition, depending on how good your translators are (from English to other languages), keeping such occurrences of *that* can facilitate translation.

There is a recent tendency in some documentation circles to use language that is more "conversational". Style guides that push this tend to recommend removing such occurrences of *that*. Similarly, style guides that promote "minimalist" text tend to recommend removing such occurrences as unnecessary noise.

Comment: There's an awful lot of POBness in this question and answer, but I still think there's a worthwhile overview of POBness, including how opinion can shift over time, and that it would be ill-judged to close-vote in this case.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I am new to this community, may I ask what do you mean by POBness?

Comment: @Sumit Kumar (1) 'I have been told that I should not use that as it hampers the readability. Any Suggestions! Is it really wrong to use that in the above example?' (a) Grammatically, both are equally valid. (b) With the complete sentence, as I say, my preference here is to include 'that' on style grounds. With another example, my preference might well be to drop it. But others may judge differently. As Drew points out, some style guides tend to be more broad-brush than this, recommending that 'that' be [almost] always included or [almost] always omitted. This essentially boils down merely ...

Comment: to the different opinions of the individuals or editorial boards. And these vary from individual to individual, from board to board. There is no 'correct' answer: the issue is _primarily opinion-based_. Such issues are almost always close-voted on ELU as not having a definitive answer.